# joining two .xls file into a single .xls file with 2 sheets

Tags: python, csv, xls

what i have is two separate csv file  and i need to convert them to .xls file and merged those .xls files into a single .xls file having two sub .xls files as two of its sheets(sheet1,sheet2).

what i come up to is successfull in creating two .xls files from .csv files.

```
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', 'D:\csvjoin\*.csv')):
   wb = xlwt.Workbook()
   ws = wb.add_sheet('data')
   with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for r, row in enumerate(reader):
           for c, val in enumerate(row):
               ws.write(r, c, val)
   wb.save(csvfile + '.xls')
```

But failed to join those two .xls into single file with two sheets.
in joined .xls file i want SHEET1 = file1.xls and SHEET2 = file2.xls

please suggest.

Comment: please re-indent the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with pandas [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method of dataframes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('path\\to\\file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('path\\to\\file2.csv')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('path\\to\\output\\file.xls')
df1.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'sheet2')
writer.save()
```

**EDIT**

or you could do it with a loop (works for pandas 0.17.0):

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('path\\to\\output\\file.xls')

i = 1
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.abspath('D:\csvjoin\*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % i)
    i += 1

writer.save()
```

Comment: what are df and df1.Are they dataframes out of those separate .xls files.please correct me.    And in which path "test.xls" will be saved,do i need to give full path name like"D:\test.xls"(before that do i also need to create an empty sheet named test.xls).

Comment: yes, you could get them from your csv files. I'll edit answer for that

Comment: you don't need to create empty test.xls, your `writer` will create new one from the path which you will set to it.

Comment: Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname='sheet1' rowx=0 colx=1      getting an error.    I think the previous code was a better option,and only needed to give where the writer save the .xls file.please explain.

Comment: may this code is doing the merging two .xls file content to single .xls file and no sheet1 sheet2 kind of thing. So the row column overwrite error.Just a guess.

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\test.xls' error when passing this to writer.

Comment: because you need to normalize it before to nominal python path. You could do it with `os.path.abspath('d:/your/path/file.xls')` or you with double slashes `d:\\your\\path\\file.xls`

Comment: @Anton-the 2nd script is clearly merging the contents into single .xls file and there overwrite error is coming.And in 1st script that os error invalid arg error is coming.So can you please make clear that which one i should try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95696/discussion-between-anton-protopopov-and-satya).